# Android: Properly horizontally centering two views for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

I know this is a question that is asked quite a lot, but none of the answers that have been provided so far have helped me resolve my problem. It's best described with pictures. I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to embed them here, but here's an imgur with three screen sizes demonstrating my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipCrP.jpg

I'm looking for a way to have the "Retrumpets" ImageButton and TextView properly centered for all screen sizes. Right now, they're currently centered using layout_centerHorizontal on the retrumpetTextView, with the retrumpetButton attached to the left of the TextView with layout_toLeftOf, like so:

```
      <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/retrumpetButton"
        android:src="@drawable/retrumpet"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/detailedTrumpetSeparationLine"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/retrumpetCountTextView"/>

      <TextView
        tools:text="30 Retrumpets"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/retrumpetCountTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trumpetTextView"/>
```

This would work perfectly, if not for the fact that what I truly want to center is a combination of BOTH of these views, so that one view or the other isn't too far to the left or right.

My question is: what is the best way to go about doing this? Can I somehow provide an adjustment value to shift both of these views a bit to the right? layout_marginStart and layout_marginLeft don't seem to work when a view is centered.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Thanks very much all! Combining the two into a horizontally centered LinearLayout did the job perfectly.

Comment: Look into drawable left for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LinearLayout to contain them.

```
   <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/trumpetTextView"     
    android:orientation = "horizontal"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/retrumpetButton"
    android:src="@drawable/retrumpet"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:layout_above="@+id/detailedTrumpetSeparationLine"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/retrumpetCountTextView"/>

       <TextView
    tools:text="30 Retrumpets"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/retrumpetCountTextView"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Or just use drawableLeft

```
<TextView
        tools:text="30 Retrumpets"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/retrumpetCountTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/retrumpet"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trumpetTextView"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put all those components i.e the "Retrumpets" ImageButton and TextView all in 1 Layout. LinearLayout. Then you can put layour gravity to this LinearLayout to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider putting the `ImageButton` and `TextViews` in a horizontal linear layout and use the weights to adjust them correctly. Try setting the `layout_weight` of each `ImageButton` to 0 and the `TextViews` each to 1.